# basic scaling double to int

Tags: java, android

i have a camera view of`x480 and y800` that is never changing

i have a screen view of `x1080 and y1780` that change from one device to anather

when a user touch screen he get`screenX and screenY` in `Int` value acording to the position he touchdown on

```
double scalingX = screenX/cameraX
```

`scalingX= 2.252.....`

i need to divide the `int touchdownX  in  double scalingX value`

the reslut must be an `int NewScreenX`

Comment: Ok, so what's the problem? You already know how to divide two numbers.

Comment: i forgot to mention the reslute must be an int i updated the  question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast the int value as double, for example:

```
double scalingX = (double)screenX / (double)cameraX;
```

and if you need the double newScreenX as an int value:

```
(int)newScreenX
```